# Pass a PHP variable from a loop via an onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This may have been answered elsewhere but I couldn't find a question which fit my circumstances.

I have a site page which out puts in DIVs records from a database, this the same DIV looped. In this DIV I have a button which brings up a modal box. This modal DIV however is not coded within the looped DIV.

I need the modal box to be able to get the ID of the record for the data which the looped DIV is showing.

The button is:

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)"onclick = "document.getElementById('light2').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
                                <div class= "obutton feature2">Reserve Book</div>
                                </a>
```

I assume I'll need to use java script somehow, but I don't know how to use it in this manner.

Ideally using some sort of form $_POST would be easiest with the form button having the set value of the $row->ID, but I can't make a form button also a  can I?

Sorry for the possibly silly question, as I've said I've found similar things asked, but always find it hard to understand the full workings on other peoples scenarios as opposed to my own.

All help appreciated -Tom

Comment: You have two JavaScript statements inside your onClick=""; Is this advisable or would it be better to pass in a function, for reasons other than readability?

Comment: I'm going to be honest and say I'm unsure of the full logic behind it, as I followed an on-line guide to produce the button and the modal box. However I know I have parts which need polishing up code wise, but I need the main functionality working right now. But I'll look into the 2 JS statements when I can :) Unless its causing an issue with what I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

I think the key to your answer is understanding how JS (and jQuery) uses *this*. When a function is called, the caller is almost always passed as the *this* variable. For example:

```
<button data-id="1234" onclick="runThisFunction()" value="run" />
<script>
function runThisFunction() {
    //Do Stuff
    var data_id = this.data('id');
};
</script>
```

In the above code, *this* contains the button that was clicked on. You can get lots of information from the *this* variable. In jQuery, you can even get to siblings, parents, or children in the DOM.

Here is an example solution to your question:

http://jsfiddle.net/yr6ds/1/

Here is a more elegant solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/yr6ds/2/

Comment: This is a lovely solution, this is my first time using jquery, so I don't fully understand it, but it looks simply enough to figure out. Also the fade in 'n out modal box is a wonderful idea :)

Comment: Actually one question, the div which the button to create the modal box will be repeated via a loop, and the info I want to show in the modal is from the loop.  So can I have the modal box echo $row->BookID and it will show the bookID of the book shown in it's parent div? or will it be the bookID of the last in he loop?

Comment: I think you want to leave the modal box blank. Then, when a button is pushed, use jQuery to put information into it, and display it.

Comment: Yeah but the values the jquery gets will be that of the specific div the button is in right? Just trying to understand the logic, because by time the jquery runs a php variable such as $bookTitle which is displayed in each div based on a while ($row = sqlquery) loop will be equal to the last book, so does it grab the variable of the displayed DIV with the clicked button?

Comment: Ok, I understand your question now. The answer is that PHP and JS(jQuery) run in two separate worlds. PHP runs on the server, and JS runs in the browser. PHP generates the page's HTML, then sends it to the browser. Once the page loads, PHP 100% stops running and everything else is JS. (unless you're using AJAX etc to get dynamic content) When Javascript runs, it can only access elements that are in the DOM, POST and URL. So your PHP variable $bookTitle is only used when PHP is echoing out the HTML. Once the page is rendered, $bookTitle disapears, and JS never sees it. Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, I understand the js in your fiddle now, and see how my question was silly, as you demonstrate what I want in it with the data-id="something", where something could be the current loop number or w/e. Thanks.

Comment: Your question wasn't silly :) We all struggle to understand things, and sometimes asking 'silly' questions is the best way to learn. Good luck learning JS and HTML!

Comment: Ok.... Why doesn't this work: http://jsfiddle.net/vereonix/Hnna6/4/ -.-' Ah ok, I needed the library enabled, what do I need in my site doc for that to work, as I think thats why it isn't working. All I have right now is:     <script type="text/javascript">    and <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>  do I need to get a file?  God I'm such a noob.

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

as found here: http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Comment: It still doesn't work for me, this is really annoying.I have exactly what is in the fiddle with the google jquery script and nothing happens. I've even made a new web page just to test it, and nothing happens, button appears can click it, but no modal box appears.

Comment: Disregard, the script has to go at the bottom of the body -.-' Why I don't know, oh well.

Comment: The browser runs and renders code from top to bottom. If you put your JS before the pertinent HTML, then when the JS runs the HTML hasn't been processed yet. There are two ways to fix it. First, you can move your JS to the end of the file. Second, you can delay your JS code until the page loads like this: $( window ).load(function() {// Run code});